# What Firebase Security Rules Should I use for this scenario?

Tags: database, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase for a production level project and was wondering how I should write my security rules. I am using session-based authentication with my project, where a cookie is sent from the frontend (after a user has logged in) to the backend, and then the userID in the cookie is used to determine the permissions to the data of that user. The user logs in with a username and password, stored in the Users collection in Firebase (Cloud Firestore).

Because of this, I thought that users could only access data that should be available to them. However, I am not sure what Firebase security rules I should write. I thought that because I am authenticating users on my backend, I can allow anyone to read/write to the database, because permissions will be automatically monitored by the backend routes using the permissions stored based on the userID. However, Firebase docs say that I shouldn't do this because if anyone guesses the project ID, they will have full access to my database. What should I do? What security rules should I write?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a look at this [Firestore security rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions).

Comment: Thanks! I've tried looking at that but because I'm not using Google-based auth I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Does this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) help you?